# Eliminar branch main cambiar de react a vue

Tags: laravel, git, vuex, gitlab

Hola hace unos días nos pidieron un proyecto React Laravel, creé un repo y subi la parte inicial, pero por dificultades y tiempo se opto por cambiarlo a Vue, pero en mi branch main ya esta lo de React - Laravel, como puedo eliminar la branch main y crearla de nuevo para subir únicamente la parte de Vue, o de que manera puedo quitar lo de React en su totalidad y subir mi nuevo repo local Laravel Vue a ese repo remoto, pd estoy en gitlab

Comment: Puedes eliminar la carpeta .git de tu local, realizar todos los cambios y luego hacer el git init, el commit inicial, vincular al repo remoto y hacer un push forzando que tome tu repo local sin tener en cuenta el remoto

Comment: Gracias Oscar, me sirvio puedes poner como respuesta tu comentario, realmente hice un ajuste no elimine el .git carpeta ni el git.ignore pero si elimine todo en mi local referente al proyecto y posterior creé uno nuevo con vue, le di push y subi primero los cambios con la eliminacion de React y se limpio mi repo remoto solo quedo el gitignore y después le di push para subir mis cambios con vue, y fue exitoso y sin problema, ya esta mi repo con Vue